# Using Jquery to create a hidden element when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is submitted to the server using jscript however i need to post the value of the submit button. This cannot be done the conventional way i must use jscript to post form. What i am doing is when the button is clicked i want to create a hidden text item with the value of the button and post that to the server. I am having some problems in creating and attaching the element to the form:

**JScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      

    $('#query').click(function(e){

         var form = $('citizenRegistration');


          var self= $("#query"),newElement = $("<input type='hidden'/>");

          alert("self value is : "+self.val());

                 //create a new element and copy attributes             
                newElement
                    .attr("name", 'user_request2')
                    .val(self.val())
                    .appendTo('.buttons');

            alert(newElement.attr("name"));

        e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).val());
        //submitPage();

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="buttons">  
    <ol>
    <li><input id="save" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Save"/>
    <input id="update" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Update"/>
    <input id="query" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Query"/>
    </li>       
    </ol>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the attribute `type` in the call to `attr()` not in the construction of the element.  Also the selector for `citizenRegistration` is missing either a `.` or a `#` depending on whether it is an id or class.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#query").click(function(e){
             var form = $("#citizenRegistration"); //Added # may need .

              //removed type=hidden, you can just use $(this)
              var self= $(this),newElement = $("<input/>");
                     //create a new element and copy attributes             
                    newElement.attr({
                            "name":"user_request2",
                            "type":"hidden" //added new attribute
                     }).val(self.val()).appendTo(".buttons");

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BXqVP/1/

You can see the hidden element when inspecting the page with firebug:

[image]

Comment: i am not seeing the element being created in your jsfiddle

Comment: Inspect the page with firebug, its there.  I also updated my answer to demonstrate that its being appended.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML I can't be certain, but I see two possible problems:

```
var form = $('citizenRegistration');
```

This is not a valid selector.  It should probably start with `#` or `.`.  You don't seem to end up using it, though.

```
.appendTo('.buttons');
```

If `.buttons` is an input element, you can't append to it.  You also shouldn't be appending to multiple `.buttons` elements, if there is more than one.  Instead, you should probably append it to `form`.  Just `.appendTo(form)` will work fine.

Comment: '.buttons' is the class name for a div element i will try form see how that works

Comment: I still cannot see the element being appended to the form anywhere

Comment: @dev_darin why would you be able to see it if it's hidden?

Comment: if i view the page source wont i be able to see it?

Comment: @dev_darin it depends; doesn't the form submit immediately?  If you're not submitting the form then "view source" won't help you, but `inspect elemetn` (firebug or chrome inspector) might

Comment: i prevented the submit just to view the source to see if i can see the element being created and attached

Comment: @dev_darin *how* are you viewing the source?

Comment: i am looking at it just sorting out some other minor errors will get back to you asap

Comment: The answer posted by Kevin Bowersox worked thank you for you assistance

Comment: I am viewing the source by right clicking and view source in fire fox

Comment: I used firebug and inspected the HTML and saw the element being created